# Setting up Django with MySQL, syncdb giving segmentation fault?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm currently working on building a Django app. I'm following the **"tangowithdjango"** tutorial, which uses Django 1.54. In their tutorial, they use Sql-lite, but I'm planning on building this app for most robust purpose, which is why I'm attempting to connect MySQL instead.

Needless to say, it's been a nightmare. I can't get MySQL to connect for the life of me.

Here's what my settings.py looks like:

```
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'app.db')

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'rideb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'nantucket',
    #'HOST': 'localhost',             # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    #'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

And here's my output I'm getting...

```
(rideb)grantmcgovern@gMAC:~/Dropbox/Developer/Projects/RideB/master$ python manage.py syncdb
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've installed `python-mysqldb`, and now I'm simply getting this, and I'm very perplexed to say the least. Is it some Django compatibility issue?

Everything works fine as the tutorial suggests with SQL-lite, but not looking to use that.

OS:

Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite

MySQL (installed via .dmg on Oracle's site):

```
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: DATABASE_PATH is for sqlite not mysql, you have to create the db using mysql command line, after that you can run syncdb to create the tables

Comment: I tried that^. I manually created a database, used that as the database name, and I got the segmentation fault.

Comment: in your code you typed 'DATABASE_PATH' (with quotes) did you named the db DATABASE_PATH, if you remove the quotes as DATABASE_PATH contains slashes (os.path.join) cannot be a valid db name.

Comment: @sax I updated my code to reflect what I'm current doing. As you can see, my database name is `rideb`, which I've created. Even still I'm getting the seg fault

Comment: add some infos about your OS, how did u install MySQL ?

Comment: @sax added OS/MySQL info in the description body.

Comment: what happen if you type `python -c "import MySQLdb"` in console ?

Comment: @sax Generates nothing at all -- no output

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Have tried all possible combinations of solutions given on various threads, but just doesn't seem to work.
Whereas sqlite3 works like a charm.
Please update if you figured out a solution!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and it turns out it was related to incorrect mysql implementation on my Mac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite). I had "mysql-connector-c" installed instead of "mysql". Uninstalling "mysql-connector-c" (brew uninstall mysql-connector-c) and installing "mysql" (brew install mysql) resolved the problem right away.

To find out if you are facing this exact problem as I did, open the Console app on your Mac, go to User Diagnostic Reports and look for the report for your crash (should start with Python_). Under queue, if it shows you "0 libmysqlclient.18.dylib", then you have the same problem as I had.

Comment: Solved my problem on Yosemite, too. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you do not need DATABASE_PATH.
My working configuration looks like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

I am using a different engine, because it is required for Python3. [→ see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)

After that you have to create the database and the user. Do not forget to give all needed rights to the user.

With `python manage.py migrate` your database is populated with your models.

`syncdb` the predecessor to migrate will be [removed in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9)